# Do accumulate() function in C++ adds negative numbers?

Tags: c++, c++14, accumulate

```
vector<int> nums={1,12,-5,-6,50,3};
int k=4;
int n=nums.size();
for(int i=0;i<=n-k;i++)
    cout<<accumulate(nums.begin()+i,nums.begin()+i+k-1,0)<<" ";
```

The output of the above code is: 8 1 39

The question is why sum of [1,12,-5,-6] is 8, which should be 2=(1+12-5-6) ?

Same for 1, which should be 51=(50+12-5-6), and

Same for 39, which should be 42=(50+3-6-5)?

Comment: `k-1` Two of these characters shouldn't be there.

Comment: Aside: I'd write this as `for (auto it = nums.begin(); it + k != nums.end(); ++it) std::cout << accumulate(it, it + k, 0) << " ";`

Answer (score 2):

If you actually do what `accumulate` does - add sequentially - and look at each partial result, you will see

```
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 12 = 13
13 + -5 = 8
8 + -6 = 2

12 + 0 = 12
12 + -5 = 7
7 + -6 = 1
1 + 50 = 51

-5 + 0 = -5
-5 + -6 = -11
-11 + 50 = 39
39 + 3 = 42
```

At this point you might spot that `accumulate`s result is the sum of the first three numbers, not four.
Then you exclaim loudly that there's a bug in `accumulate` that makes it disregard the last element.
And then you look at the documentation and notice that the end of the range is "one past the last element", so your end iterator, `nums.begin() + i + 4 - 1`, says that the element before it (that is, `*(begin() + i + 2)`, the third element from `begin() + i`) is the last element *inside* the range.
All iterator ranges (and index intervals) in the standard library are half-open in this manner.

The solution is to remove the `-1` from the end iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If your hypothesis is that `std::accumulate` doesn't treat negative numbers in the conventional way, then test it directly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums={1,12,-5,-6,50,3};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + 4, 0);
}
```

The output is 2, corresponding to `1 + 12 - 5 - 6`.

The issue is in your code; and in your iterator addition. Specifically, the first two parameters of `std::accumulate` are both relative to `nums.begin()`: you need to drop the `-1` from the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is the position *just after* the last element to deal with.

The `-1` in `nums.begin()+i+k-1` is preventing the last element to deal with from being processed, so you should remove that.